# Execute dynamic query with Linq in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have:

```
string table_name = "Orders";
string column_name = "Name";
string identity_column = "OrderID"
int identity_value = 5;
```

How can I achieve the following (dynamically):

```
var result = (from order in db.Orders
              where order.OrderId== identity_value 
              select order).SingleOrDefault();
```

For security reasons i cannot create a whole sql query and then execute it to server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically generate LINQ queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505189/dynamically-generate-linq-queries)

Comment: already checked that. i have a different scenario.

Comment: ah yes, i can see what you mean. I don't think you can dynamically set those items in LINQ. But i'd like to be proved wrong!

Answer (score 0):

```
`System.Linq.Dynamic` library will help you generating dynamic query which has extension method

Where(string predicate,params object[] values)
```

To use this first include the namespace

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

then construct the predicate at run time

```
string predicate = "OrderId = @0";
int identity_value = 5;
```

then query db.Orders

```
db.Orders.AsQueryable().Where(predicate,identity_value);
```

Comment: the table is also dynamic. I need to find the table based on its name!