# How can I query an unknown property with ASP/MVC Entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a form where the user selects a property that ends up getting used in a query. Since I don't know what that property will be, my query has to do it 'dynamically' so I wrote the following code in hopes of not having to write a ton of if/else statements since MyType has a ton of properties

```
MyType content = null;
foreach (var prop in typeof(MyType).GetProperties())
{
    if (userProperty == prop.Name)
    {    
        content = db.MyType.Where(mt =>
            mt.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name)
            .GetValue(mt).ToString() == someOtherValue)
        .FirstOrDefault();
        break;
    }
}
```

which results in

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
```

After a bit of research I learned this is because the Entity framework does not support the use of all methods within its query builder methods. Ok, So I think to myself that I just need to store the fetched property value in a variable first and then just plug that into the Where query.....but how would I do this? I obviously can't declare a variable within the Where method, but it's only in the context of the Where method that I can get a hold on my value.

At this point I see myself having two options.

1. Bite the bullet and just write a ton (like 35) of if/else statements
   with duplicate code in them
2. Fetch all of the MyType content from the
   database as a List and then have freedom

Option one is unappealing for obvious reasons, and option two just seems extremely inefficient to me as there is a huge amount of data in the database and I only need one row of it.

So....what can I do? I know there has to be a way to accomplish this how I want, but I just don't know how.

Comment: Use linqkit and pass in the predicate to the where clause. You'll still have a bunch of if statements, but you'll only have one linq statement at the end

Comment: check out these answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505189/dynamically-generate-linq-queries