# Dynamic Linq Query with multiple select value's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, select

I want to implement a filter on multiple columns, but I don't want to write
 for every column a new query. So I implemented a GetDistinctProperty function which looks like this :

```
public ActionResult GetDistinctProperty(string propertyName)
{
    var selector = CreateExpression<TDomain>(propertyName);
    var query = this.InventoryService.GetAll(Deal);
    var results = query.Select(selector).Distinct().ToList();
    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private static Expression<Func<T, object>> CreateExpression<T>(string propertyName)
{
    // Specify the type we are accessing the member from
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression body = param;

    // Loop through members in specified property name
    foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))
    {
        // Access each individual property
        body = Expression.Property(body, member);
    }

    var conversion = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
    // Create a lambda of this MemberExpression 
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, param);
}
```

Let's take as example that I have as propertyName SiteIdentifier.

The selector gives me as value

```
{x => Convert(x.SiteIdentifier)}
```

and when I want to see the results it gives me the following error :

```
Unable to cast the type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object'.
LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

When I try the select as follow :

```
var results = query.Select(x=>x.SiteIdentifier).Distinct().ToList();
```

it works.

Anyone any Idea?

Comment: This is not a valid syntax : `{x => Convert(x.SiteIdentifier)}` unless you have a function named `Convert` that accepts a single parameter.

Comment: No I know, that is the result of the CreateExpression<TDomain>(propertyName); and I want it like this x=>x.SiteIdentifier

Comment: how to do you get `propertyName` to pass to `GetDistinctProperty` method?

Comment: It's from the view, it passes the Columnname

Comment: You might want to look at [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) (also the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505189/dynamically-generate-linq-queries))

Comment: what is the reason of `var conversion = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));`?

Comment: change return value Expression<Func<T, object>> to Expression<Func<T, string>> it should work

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/723018/1380428) can be helpful. Be sure to read @ConnellWatkins's comment at that answer.

Comment: When I remove the expression.convert it works but not when my datatype is a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to pass the property name as string when using Linq in a statically typed language. Generics and delegates (Func) got introduced to make this kind of logic obsolete.

You can simply pass the expression instead of passing the property name:

```
public ActionResult GetDistinctProperty(Expression<Func<TDomain, TProp> selector)
{
    var query = this.InventoryService.GetAll(Deal);
    var results = query.Select(selector).Distinct().ToList();
    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Usage:

```
GetDistinctProperty(x=> x.SiteIdentifier);
```

Comment: This is not what I want, now I have to call for each property the function. I just want to create a dynamic x=>x.Propertyname

Comment: @Walter What do you mean by *I have to call for each property the function* ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although `IQueryable<T>` interface is covariant, covariance is not supported for value types, so `IQueryable<int>` cannot be treated as `IQueryable<object>`. From the other side, EF does not like casting value type to `object`.

So in order to make it work, you need to resort to non generic `IQueryable` interface. Unfortunately almost all `Queryable` extension methods are build around `IQueryable<T>`, so you have to manually compose a corresponding calls.

For instance, in order to select property by name (path), you'll need something like this:

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions()
{
    public static IQueryable SelectProperty(this IQueryable source, string path)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "x");
        var property = path.Split(',')
            .Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);
        var selectCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Select", new[] { parameter.Type, property.Type },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(selectCall);
    }
}
```

But then you'll need a `Distinct` method that works on `IQueryable`:

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions()
{
    public static IQueryable Distinct(this IQueryable source)
    {
        var distinctCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Distinct", new[] { source.ElementType },
            source.Expression);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(distinctCall);
    }
}
```

Now you have all the necessary pieces to implement the method in question. But there is another important detail though. In order to be able to create `List<object>` you need to call `Cast<object>`. But if you use `IQueryable.Cast` extension method you'll get the same not supported exception from EF. So you need to call explicitly the `IEnumerable.Cast` instead:

```
public ActionResult GetDistinctProperty(string propertyName)
{
    var query = this.InventoryService.GetAll(Deal);
    var results = Enumerable.Cast<object>(
        query.SelectProperty(propertyName).Distinct()).ToList();
    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```