# Dynamic Linq does not remember properties of a property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic-linq

I am using Dynamic Linq to sort my database based on a string. However it throws an error saying:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

The reason for this is because I am doing an order by like this: `q => OrderBy("Purchase.Date", false))`, so it should generate something like `OrderBy(x => x.Purchase.Date)`, while in reality it just says `OrderBy(x => x.Date)`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505189/dynamically-generate-linq-queries

Comment: What is the type of `Purchase` property? The exception posted is usually thrown  when you access `Date` property of a `DateTime` value.