# Can you add a string value to a linq search?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var model = _context.models.AsQueryable().Where(e => e.items.Any() && e.price.Any());
```

returns models with any items and any price, correct, this is working. However if any values wont be decided until user selection is it anyway possible to do something like

```
//user selection
string tempValueToSearch = "items";

//create query
string query = "e." + tempValueToSearch + ".Any()";
```

can this become?

```
var model = _context.models.AsQueryable().Where(e => query && e.price.Any());
```

failing with operator && cant be applied to type string and bool

Comment: google dynamic linq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically generate LINQ queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505189/dynamically-generate-linq-queries)